# SSH Tunneling socks, flash plugin always crash

Tags: ssh, tunnel

Hello I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, I am tunneling my connections to my server so that I can access country restrictions but I don't know why when I access a flash website, the flash player always crash. Youtube seems to work fine but Hulu and other sites doesn't work. So How can I fix this?

This is my socks tunnel:

ssh admin@remoteip -L 1234:localhost:1234

Answer (score 0):

That's not setting up a SOCKS proxy; that's just forwarding a single port. You may want to try something like `ssh -D 1234 admin@remoteip` instead.

Comment: hello, i also tried that method but it isn't working in flash. flash is always crashing except youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your browser to use a SOCKS proxy on localhost:1234 after executing `ssh -D 1234 admin@remoteip`?